# How to prevent scrolling UIScrollView with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

`UICollectionView` has **Bounces** **enabled** however I can't use it because `UIScrollView` is scrolling at the same time.
How to prevent scrolling the `UIScrollView` when I scroll inside the `UICollectionView`?

This doesn't work:

```
myScrollView.isExclusiveTouch = true
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Set ContentSize of the UIScrollView as UIView size.

Comment: I would advise staying away from putting a UICollectionView inside a UIScrollView as it is buggy and can result in unexpected behaviours. I would suggest looking into inserting a header or footer view into your UICollectionView to display the content that you would want inside the UIScrollView.

Comment: @ImadAli It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contentSize of the UIScrollView as:

Swift:

```
let scrollableSize = CGSize(width: <View Width>, height: <View Height>)
scrollView.contentSize = scrollableSize
```

Objective-C:

```
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(<View Width>, <View Height>);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

Another Option Could be:

```
myScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Stops Horizontal Scrolling:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    sender.contentOffset.x = 0.0
}
```

Stops Vertical Scrolling:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    sender.contentOffset.y = 0.0
}
```